# How do callbacks work in a recursive call using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback

I want to know how Javascript handles callbacks inside a recursive call, are the callbacks pushed right into the queue on each of the recursive calls or after the call resolves with a base case?

**Test case code**

```
function enums(start,end,callback) {
  callback(start);
  if (end == 1)
    return 1;
  else{
    return enums(start + 1, end - 1, callback);
  }
}

var callback = function (number){
   console.log(number);
}
enums(1,10,callback);
```

Comment: You can both test and verify this by simply running your code in the console. As long as you're not running async code, the code is executed in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive calls are handled the same way as any other programming language.
The code will be  as executed as if you were iterating on array and call a function inside the loop.
If you would span a timer using setTimeout with a delay of 0 milliseconds after  calling your enums function you will notice that the setTimeout callback will be executed after the return of the recursion.

```
function enums(start,end,callback) {
   callback(start);
   if (end == 1)
      return 1;
   else{
      return enums(start + 1, end - 1, callback);
   }
}

var callback = function (number){
  console.log(number);
}
enums(1,10,callback);
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Rick"); }, 0);
```

the output should be: 1..10 and then Rick